# Firestore admin SDK paginate through listDocuments() to include deleted documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using the Firebase Nodejs admin SDK, I need to retrieve a list of documents including deleted documents (as they still have sub-collections that need to be retrieved.

I need to retrieve them using some sort of pagination, given it is a large list that is to be later displayed in a UI.

How can I query, including deleted documents, using pagination/cursors?

.listDocuments() works from a collection reference where I cannot use .limit() & .startAt()
The REST API for listDocuments supports pageSize & pageToken params and appears to paginate by default when testing (see link below).
The NodeJS admin sdk listDocuments() does not appear to support pagination and somehow retrieves all items in one go which is not what we want.

Have I misunderstood or is there a gap in the NodeJS implementation?
Are there any other approaches to achieve the outcome while minimising the number of reads?

Thanks for your time.
John

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listDocuments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the docs for the REST/gRPC API [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listDocuments), you can specify `pageSize` - which would be equivalent to specifying a `limit` - and a `pageToken` - which would allow the same use-case as `startAt`.

At first glance I indeed don't see the same options in the Node.js Admin SDK, so it indeed looks like for the moment you'll have to use the REST API to get this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Is the github repo the best place to raise an issue/feature request for something like this? I'd like to say that I'm surprised that this isn't an existing issue for others but nothing surprises me in software :)